# Modify the default report folder of pitest target/pit-reports/YYYYMMDDHHMI

Tags: pitest

is it possible to rename the report default folder ?

I don't want to have "YYYYMMDDHHMI", I'm trying to rename it to something simple and constant. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the `timestampedReports` parameter. If you set it to `false` pitest will use a constant location.